# Object.assign(...) attempts to set properties without setters

Tags: javascript

When specifically defining a get-only property on an object, and then attempting to assign another object on top of the original, `Object.assign` seems to not care whether or not a target property is read-only:

```
var myObj = {
    firstName: "Jimbo",
  lastName: "Smythe"
};

Object.defineProperty(myObj, "fullName", {
    get: function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
});

Object.assign(myObj, {
  fullName: "Jimbo T. Smythe"
});
```

This causes the following exception:

> TypeError: Cannot set property fullName of # which has only a getter

Is this not a bug in `Object.assign`?

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fa8j7p5j/

Comment: From MDN "In case of an error, for example if a property is non-writable, a TypeError will be raised, and the target object remains unchanged."

Comment: I don't understand the problem, it throws an error, what else would you expect?

Comment: And in the spec https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.assign 4.c.ii.2. `Set(to, nextKey, propValue, true).` the last `true` means throw TypeError if fail

Comment: @OmriAharon I would have expected it to skip over read-only properties since they would never be writable.

Comment: That's probably a gap in what you expect I guess. Certainly not a bug :)

Comment: @OmriAharon Apparently so.

Comment: I think the real question here is how can you safely use `Object.assign` at all if you don't know if there are read only properties somewhere in the object tree.

Answer (score 2):

So i think the real problem here is that previously `Object.assign` never had a situation like this where it could cause an exception. And now there is because read only properties exist. Now there is no way to blindly use `assign` on two unknown objects because it could explode.

Unfortunately, until a new `Object.assignSafe` method is added the only way around this is to protect from these bad properties.

```
/**
 * This function performs an Object.assign but does not explode on trying to set a read-only property
 * @param  {Object} target  Target to apply sources properties to
 * @param  {Array<Object>} sources Any number of sources to be applied to target
 * @return {Object}        The updated target object;
 */
function assignSafe(target, ...sources) {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(target);
    const safe = sources.map(source => {
        let entries = Object.entries(source);
        let reduced = entries.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, currentValue[0]);
            if (!descriptor || descriptor.set) {
                accumulator.push(currentValue);
            }
            return accumulator;
        }, []);
        return Object.fromEntries(reduced);
    });
    return Object.assign(target, ...safe);
}
```